# Restricting users to execute queries that bloat up tempdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, tempdb

we have many a times faced a scenario where bad queries using tempdb just bloats up this system database filling 700 GB of tempdb in like couple of hours.

I know there is a scope to tune them up. But as of now there are quite a few no of users and handling the queries involves lot of time for now.

So can we use a process like RG to restrict these users to bloat tempdb or any other way. Just looking if there is any such alternative available?